# Where's the shared libraries in iTunes 12.1.2 for Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows, home-sharing

I can't seem to find it, and all the other solutions are for when the sidebar existed. I am using Windows 7 & OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to first sign in to Home Sharing on all devices (iOS, Windows, Mac) with one Apple ID. It can be any AppleID - not the one you use for other purchases - just that it is one ID across all the "sharing"

Then the libraries show up in the top left under the play, rewind, fast forward buttons.

[image]

The Mac should see the PC and vice versa. You also can use any iOS device to connect to both the PC and Mac libraries. With three devices, you can rule out any one failure.

Also, iTunes needs to be running on both computers.

Comment: I have signed in on both my devices, yet the libraries do not show up on the left on my PC.

Comment: @lempamo Does the Mac see the PC? Do you have a third device? Can you disconnect your router from the internet and then disable all firewall / anti virus protection to see if that's blocking things?

Comment: The Mac sees the PC, I don't have a third device, my firewall is off, and my virus software only scans the filesystem.

Comment: @lempamo You might need a third device. It seems you know where to look for the shared library, but if the network agents can't connect and see each other, you'll need to diagnose the network failure or isolate the one software stack that's not working.